# How Can I Get Bios Date in 64Bit System

Tags: c, date, windows-7, 64-bit, bios

i would like to write a program in c that gets the bios date for 64 bit windows 7. How can i do this?

Comment: Any reason the system clock isn't good enough?

Comment: I believe you would need to write a driver that gives you read access to a very low memory range, 0-FFFFF and then have your c program use the driver to read these low pages and know the right offset of where your bios stores the date.

I don't know if this is how it works so I'm just making an educated guess

Comment: I am not sure if it is directly accessible from Windows. When your computer boots all the BIOS functions are available, however, after the operating system begins to start it leaves real mode and most of the BIOS functions become inaccessible. Windows probably captures the system time from the BIOS during boot and stores it, then simply increments that stored value to calculate current time.

Comment: If you're willing/able to move to C++, look into WMI: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa389762%28v=VS.85%29.aspx